# Removing the ScatterViewItem on clicking a button

Tags: wpf, pixelsense, scatterview

My group is developing a surface project for school and we are all quite new to this technology. The situation is :

We have a page with 4 surface buttons. Whenever a user click/tap on one of the surface buttons, a popup image will come out. Since this app is made for multi-user environment, if another user tap the same button, there will be another popup but the same image. I have a close button on each popup to close it when user finish seeing the image.

Whenever the button is clicked, a canvas, grid and ScatterViewItem, and a button on each ScatterViewItem will be created.

The problem I'm having now is that the close button on each ScatterViewItem can close the popup. However, it only works if it's only one popup. When there are multiple popups, the buttons will close the last popup only. Anybody has any suggestion? Really appreciated . Thanks in advance

Below is the code:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Image imageControl = new Image();
            Grid grid = new Grid();

            // changing to popup from image control

            Canvas cv1 = new Canvas();
            cv1.ClipToBounds = true;
            cv1.Width = 350;
            cv1.Height = 350;
            cv1.SetValue(Canvas.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent));

            Image imageControl1 = new Image();
            var myBitmapImage1 = new BitmapImage();
            myBitmapImage1.BeginInit();
            myBitmapImage1.UriSource = new Uri("/Images/btn1.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            myBitmapImage1.EndInit();
            imageControl1.Source = myBitmapImage1;
            imageControl1.Width = 250;
            imageControl1.Height = 250;

            Button sb1 = new Button();
            sb1.Content = "Close";
            sb1.Width = 40;
            sb1.Height = 40;

            imageControl1.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, -40.0);

            sb1.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 180.0);
            sb1.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 2.0);
            sb1.Click +=new RoutedEventHandler(Close_Click);

            cv1.Children.Add(imageControl1);
            cv1.Children.Add(sb1);
            grid.Children.Add(cv1);

            App.svi = new ScatterViewItem();

            App.svi.Content = grid;
          sv.Items.Add(App.svi);

         App. svi.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            Surfaceapp1.Show();


        }

   public void Close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button srcButton = e.Source as Button;

      App.svi.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each 'popup' that you put out (the ScatterView) is a unique object on the surface.  So a close on one does not relate to any other ScatterViewthat you've created.  In the event you want all of them to close there are only a few things you can do:

You could keep only a single ScatterView on the surface.  You could keep a reference to it and when the button is clicked a second time it could be a trigger event to animate the original ScatterView causing attention to be drawn to it.  (making sure you also give it focus)

The other approach is keep your logic asis, but build a list of each control you build.  That way when you get a close event, you go into that list and call a close on each instance in your list.  Naturally, each list would be indirectly associated with each button on the form.  You would want to put your hook into the Closing event on each ScatterView so that you know when one of them is being closed.  Since you have multiple objects on the table you need to also assume that there can be multiple clicks so you need to make your logic thread safe when you process closing the entire list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I'm a student and has very little experience in wpf, I don't really understand what you want to say. Can you please explain me how to do the 2nd approach ?

Comment: I want to do something like this but not in xaml but in the code behind.                                 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804980(v=surface.10).aspx   Other than the pictures becoming greyscale, I want to make each of them disappear by clicking on their own buttons. But the problem now is when I hav multiple images, tapping on the last image works but the previous images lost their click event and even if I tap on the other images' buttons, they will only close the last image.